# Convex optimisation for holomorphic functions

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization

Convexity/concavity are useful properties of a function when performing optimisation, as one can rest assured that the found solution is the global minimum/maximum. For a real function of one or two variables, convexity is also straightforward to visualize; however, for functions in the complex domain, I specifically deal with holormorphic functions, the notion of convexity seems to be mathematically ill defined. At least all books that I consulted instead generalise convexity to plurisubharmonicity. Is it possible to naively consider the complex vector space $\mathbb C^{n}$ as isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{2n}$ and optimise a problem on the this hypersurface or does plurisubharmonicity ensure any properties that are similar to convexity for real functions?

Comment: You have to specify in more detail how you would do that - you would have to single out one real direction which would be the cost function you want to minimize. Then, the question would be if holomorphicity is still any useful in that scenario. Without specifying the type of optimization scenario, this is pretty much ill-defined (or overly broad).

Comment: Also note that, if I remember correctly, e.g. harmonic functions have no maxima, so this constrains the type of things you can optimize  ...

Comment: imagine the concave maximisation $A(b) = sup_{c}[E(c) − \int c(r) b(r) dr]$, where b is some complex function (holomorphic for simplicity?). The supremum is only a problem with complex numbers, so simplistic guess is to make the complex component of b another axis and optimise into the concave cone? $b$ and $c$ are related by Legendre-Fenchel transform.